# Firebase rules in which a user can edit data of another user if he clicked on his profile

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I have developed an app using firebase realtime database. In the app, if e-g user 1 clicks on the profile of user 2 then the data of user 2 would be changed. User 1 can only change the data of other users if he clicks on their profiles. I have written some rules to secure my database but these rules won't allow user 1 to change the data of other users if he clicks on their profile. You help will be highly appreciated. Thank You
Below is my code:
**Firebase Rules**
[image: Firebase Rules]
**Database Structure**

[image: My Database structure]

**Java Code which will change user data if his profile is clicked**

```
  holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

               dRef.child(modelClass.get(position).userID).child("showGigCount").setValue(modelClass.get(position).getShowGigCount()-1); // this will decrease showGigCount for clicked users
                dRef.child(modelClass.get(position).getUserID()).child("clicksOnProfile").setValue(modelClass.get(position).getClicksOnProfile()+1); // this will increase clicksOnProfile for clicked users
                dRef.child(modelClass.get(position).getUserID()).child("lifeTimeClicksOnProfile").setValue(modelClass.get(position).getLifeTimeClicksOnProfile()+1); // this will increase clicksOnProfile for clicked users
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want to allow certain properties to be modified by all users, which you can do with:

```
...
"$user_id": {
  ".write": "auth != null && $user_id === auth.uid",
  "showGigCount": {
    ".write": "auth != null"
  },
  "clicksOnProfile": {
    ".write": "auth != null"
  },
  "lifeTimeClicksOnProfile": {
    ".write": "auth != null"
  },
}
...
```

The added rules give permission to write the lower level properties, while your original write rules on `$user_id` still rejects writing other properties of the user.